# Excel VBA: Two users one PC, user A performance is 5-10x better

Tags: excel, vba, windows, office365

IN SHORT:
I have an Excel XLSB file with some pretty complex VBA code in it that iterates through a folder of XLSB files, opens each one by one, grabs some data, and closes it, then at the very end acts upon the collected data from all files. I have two users, myself and a colleague, that share one PC. My colleague sees significantly worse performance running the same VBA automated tasks under the same conditions. Why?

---

Please note that this question is *not* about the method we've used to store and then gather this data - for complex reasons I don't need to go into here we have no other choice but to use VBA and Excel. Please do not give me tips on improving my VBA code or alternative solutions, that is not the problem at hand here.

OKAY with that out of the way!

I have two users, myself (User A) and my colleague (User B), who have accounts on a single Windows PC, sharing the file with VBA on a network drive (let's call this file and the VBA code it runs "Automation"). The files we iterate through are on the PC's C: Drive, shared with both users. When User A is logged in, Automation runs at approximately 15 files per minute. When User B is logged in, Automation runs at about 2 files per minute. We sometimes must iterate over 1,000+ files, which can mean a difference of HOURS.

I've done everything I can think of to determine why. As far as I cna tell we both have identical user permissions, Window settings, Excel settings, and so on. We use identical PERSONAL.XLSB files (and I've tried removing it altogether for both of us). We've tried installing Office 365 from scratch, wiping the OS and starting from scratch, even a brand new PC. I've compared screenshots of all the Task Manager tabs while Automation is running, and they're more or less identical - nothing stands out as significantly different. Nothing seems to help.

So my question to you is - what the heck could cause two user accounts on the same PC to see significantly different performance when running a VBA automated task from the same file, iterating over the same files??

Any ideas you can give me are appreciated.

Comment: Even if you don't want "tips" it would still be useful to share the basic VBA code here.  Have you tried running simple timings tests where you try to narrow down where the differences are in performance?  Are both PC accounts local, or are you on a larger Active Directory setup?  If Yes to the last one then UserB's profile may be corrupted or need to be reset.

Comment: @TimWilliams It's an Active Directory setup. Any idea what would be corrupted in B's profile that would cause massive slowdown of iterating through files? Good idea with adding additional timing tests, I'll add some between each major operation and see what we can find out.

Comment: I have no idea what might cause a slowdown, but it would likely be faster to re-create UserB's profile than to try to figure out the root cause.

Comment: Fair point! Thanks for the thoughts.